# esri JavaScript API symbolize layers

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a working application here: http://dola.colorado.gov/gis-cms/sites/default/files/html/census2000v2.html

I'm using the JavaScript API with ArcGIS Online.  I have a bunch of layers loaded and pre-symbolized in an AGOL 'Web Map'.

I'd like to be able to customize the symbology of each layer dynamically using JavaScript.  I'd ideally like to use a renderer and be able to create a different symbology for each demographic variable.

I've run into a major brick wall.  To be able to change the symbology, I need to be able to iterate through graphics in a feature set - yet I have no idea where to get a feature set object from.  All the examples I see use 'Feature Layers' loaded through URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first you need to get the layer from the webmap:

```
var featureLayer = mapObject.getLayer(layerName)
```

Then you can query the `featurelayer`, which will return a `featureSet`.

Here is an example:

```
var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
query.outFields = ["*"];

featureLayer.queryFeatures(query, function(featureSet) {
    //do something with the featureSet here!
});
```